# how to write php MySql query

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to be able to make a selection from a select-box and view the selected table.

My skill level with php/MySQL at this point is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM electrical ORDER BY item_id LIMIT $offset, $RPP";
```

With this query the `div` is populated on page load.

I have a select box that has 6 choices:

```
<form>
    <select name="dbtables" onchange="showTable(this.value)" id="selectBox">
        <option value="">Select a materials table:</option> 
        <option value="" id="hr"></option> 
        <option value="equipment">Worker Equipment</option>
        <option value="tool">General Tools</option>
        <option value="electrical">Electrical Materials</option>
        <option value="mechanical">Mechanical Materials</option>
        <option value="plumbing">Plumbing Materials</option>
        <option value="hvac">HVAC Materials</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Each choice is a table in a single MySQL database.

Script for `showTable` is working, after making selection alert shows choice picked.

```
function showTable(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("materials").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("materials").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    alert(str);
}
```

Any pointers or help is appreciated appreciated.

Comment: After some research I need to look into MySQL joins, I have 6 tables and need to return matches on the Category column based on what is picked in the select-box. Thanks

Comment: Then you should answer yourself and mark it as accepted, so other will learn what you found out.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the SQL-query to execute on your database. What you should do is to insert the `q`-variable from the query string into the SQL-query like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $_REQUEST['q'] . " ORDER BY item_id LIMIT $offset, $RPP";
```

Ofcourse you should check or escape the variables to prevent SQL injections, using something like `mysql_real_escape_string`, but that's not really the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1):

in your index.php pick the $str value using $_GET method and construct the query. then run that query and echo the data. after that, you can call this function in the script file after alert().

```
function useHttpResponse() {
   if (http.readyState == 4) {
    if(http.status == 200) {
       var txt = http.responseText;
    var response_msg="<h4><span class='darkblue'>" + txt + "</span></h4>"
       document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = response_msg;
    }
  } else { //you may skip this else portion
  document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = '<img src="images/loading.gif" /><span class="darkblue">retrieving data...</span>';
  }
}
```

here your fetched data will show on a div with id "showtime". during the fetching the time a loading gif will be visible in the "showtime" div. or you may skip that else portion.
hope that function will help you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer any aspect of the question, only reapeat part of the code in the question in another way using different names which just serves to confuse more than help.

Comment: in that case he need to check his query in the server side php file.

Comment: you can see first line in my answer is to pick the $str value from in the serverside index.php file and construct the query. then why is it confusing? ya, the method of script is different.

Comment: Not really, as `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` is used to register a function in the event-handler for changes in the ready state of `xmlhttp`. When this is set up before calling `open()` and `send(null)` on `xmlhttp` the function will be called every time the ready state of `xmlhttp` changes, which is what your suggestion does in a separate function. Except your suggestion will only try it once, which might result in the function being called before the `xmlhttp` gets eny answer.

Comment: Well, the question shows knowledge of PHP, JavaScript and Ajax-calls. I think what the asker wants is help on building the SQL-query to retrieve the content of the chosen table.